# What is the most effective way to set up a private government?

Tags: internal-consistency, government

**Note:** I am by no means hitting on anything about any country all of this question is fiction and its resemblance to any country is pure co-incidental.

Politicians are the most immoral, corrupt, inefficient, lazy people on the planet. Leave them behind and join a private government run by hardworking and honest people. Alas so much for the big talk.

But here is the story:

> The guy in question is a rich person of an influential family and enjoys considerable influence in his hometown (which incidentally isn't really big on the current government's agenda unless it's election time). The protagonist is aware of this and wants to end this shitocracy. The main question is **How?**

By a private govt our protagonist wants to develop industries and factories buy up plots and lands and construct schools and colleges and hospitals on them slowly his profits via the factories allow to buy enough land to replace the current (incumbent) government by a democratic technocracy

Note: The question is partly inspired by this movie: ['Shivaji: The Boss'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sivaji_(film))

Comment: This "private   government"   is  a separatist  movement? Revolution? Or  what, exactly?

Comment: A politician must run for office.  So a private government would be staffed by people who do not run for office.  Like a big corporation, or a dictatorship.  Hitler's rise to power is instructive.

Comment: *"Politicians are the most moralless, corrupt, inefficient, lazy people on the planet"*. Down-vote for lazy and demeaning trope. Vote To Close for being duplicate of a question asked earlier today.

Comment: Look up what the Cadbury family did with Bournville in the UK, they created a new town in which they were the only employer in the town, the primary landowners and provided many of the things we would expect a socialist government to provide today. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bournville I imagine the workers had a lot more loyalty to the Cadbury's than they did to the national government.

Comment: The other question is on hold, too. You guys are going crazy on the holds. It's not like this is a discussion about cancer treatments. The stakes are low: lighten up!

Comment: @Neal I don't know about anyone else's feeling on it but this week feels chaff heavy from where I'm sitting.

Comment: http://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2017/10/25/560045944/tesla-turns-power-back-on-at-childrens-hospital-in-puerto-rico

Answer (score 4):

The official government, in any given area, is the organization that has the monopoly on violence.

So, whose orders do the cops follow? There are myriad examples of police with divided loyalties; it's probably more common than not. If you're in multiple jurisdictions, you'll need some discretion, but, you know, as a Texan, I assure you: you don't need much.

How to proceed: gradually make your bribery/ownership of cops more open. Ensure that those who benefit have more power (money, class, or numbers) than those who are harmed. Keep it local. Don't provoke the feds.

Comment: Cynical, but sadly true. It isn't just the police though; one can have one's own hired muscle and sufficient influence to not be bothered

Comment: True! Goon squads that outpower the cops become the violence monopoly... until the governor calls in the National Guard. : )

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was going to say, with the example of small rural towns effectively owned and run by a long standing family or group of families.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest issue is the modern Nation-State was born out of the 30 years war and the outline was set by the [Peace of Westphalia](https://infogalactic.com/info/Peace_of_Westphalia) in 1648. The Nation State improved and expanded its ability to survive through developing more efficient systems of taxation, bureaucratic control of manpower and resources and the ability to field military forces and sustain them in the field batter than any competing system of organization or government. Historians like [Niall Ferguson](https://infogalactic.com/info/Niall_Ferguson) have written about this process at length.

So the short answer is you are not going to do this because the armed power of established States will simply overwhelm you. This explains the lack of "microstates", the impossibility of "sea steading" and a multitude of other schemes to diminish or delete the power of the State over individuals or groups. You could set up the "People's Democratic Meritocracy of Smithsville", but the second you fail to pay taxes or otherwise defy the power of the State your polity is in, the Police or Armed Forces will arrive, arrest the ringleaders, execute warrants to collect taxes owed and otherwise remind you who is really in charge. (Current events in Spain as of the time of writing should make that point abundantly clear).

There are really only two alternatives.

1. For all practical purposes, if you feel a private corporation can execute the job of managing a town better than an elected government, then the town can incorporate into a condominium or something similar. This solution ignores the fact that cities actually are "incorporated", the condo board replicated the city council and corporations are just as rife with internal politics as any city, county or other political division.
2. Call Elon Musk and arrange to get off the Earth altogether. This has the singular advantage of removing yourself from the armed power of any Earthly State (unless they choose to follow you), but the Mars colony will need to have an organization to manage the various resources needed to live and survive; probably an elected board of directors or elected councillors.

The real issue here isn't that elected officials are stupid, but rather there are a multitude of biological and institutional incentives for people to behave the way they do once in elected office. The real challenge is to devise a system of incentives which is both reasonable (many theoretical political systems fail because they go against human nature) and enforceable. Since we haven't seemed to have had much luck, the fall back is to use what has worked in the past, and so far a Republican form of government, backed by a fairly distinct set of cultural preferences (long time horizons, deferred gratification, balance between individual and group and cooperation at the lowest level using a multitude of voluntary associations, free markets and the unfettered use of personal property) seems to have worked the best.

Your Martian colonists may avoid a lot of what passes for government these days because they will be too busy trying to survive in a hostile wilderness that they won't have a lot of time for "politics" in the usual sense.